# Scrapy spider isn't iterating over list of start-urls

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm attempting to build an email scraper that takes in a csv file of urls, and returns them with email addresses; including additional urls/addresses that get scraped in the process. I can't seem to get my spider to iterate through each row in the csv file, even through they're returned fine when I test the function I'm calling.

Here's the code; which I adapted from [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/web-scraping-to-extract-contact-information-part-1-mailing-lists-854e8a8844d2):

```
import os, re, csv, scrapy, logging
import pandas as pd
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml import LxmlLinkExtractor
from googlesearch import search
from time import sleep

# Avoid getting too many logs and warnings when using Scrapy inside Jupyter Notebook.
logging.getLogger('scrapy').propagate = False

# Extract urls from file.
def get_urls():
    urls = pd.read_csv('food_urls.csv')
    url = list(urls) 
    for i in url: 
        return urls

# Test it.
# get_urls()

# Create mail spider.
class MailSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'email'

    def parse(self, response):
#       Search for links inside URLs.
        links = LxmlLinkExtractor(allow=()).extract_links(response)

#       Take in a list of URLs as input and read their source codes one by one.
        links = [str(link.url) for link in links]
        links.append(str(response.url))

#       Send links from one parse method to another.
        for link in links:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=link, callback=self.parse_link) 

#   Pass URLS to the parse_link method — this is the method we'll apply our regex findall to look for emails            
    def parse_link(self, response):

        html_text = str(response.text)
        mail_list = re.findall('\w+@\w+\.{1}\w+', html_text)

        dic = {'email': mail_list, 'link': str(response.url)}
        df = pd.DataFrame(dic)

        df.to_csv(self.path, mode='a', header=False)
        df.to_csv(self.path, mode='a', header=False)

# Save emails in a CSV file
def ask_user(question):
    response = input(question + ' y/n' + '\n')
    if response == 'y':
        return True
    else:
        return False
def create_file(path):
    response = False
    if os.path.exists(path):
        response = ask_user('File already exists, replace?')
        if response == False: return 

    with open(path, 'wb') as file: 
        file.close()

# Combine everything 
def get_info(root_file, path): 
    create_file(path)
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['email', 'link'], index=[0])
    df.to_csv(path, mode='w', header=True)

    print('Collecting urls...')
    urls_list = get_urls()

    print('Searching for emails...')
    process = CrawlerProcess({'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    process.crawl(MailSpider, start_urls=urls_list, path=path)
    process.start()

    print('Cleaning emails...')
    df = pd.read_csv(path, index_col=0)
    df.columns = ['email', 'link']
    df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='email')
    df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
    df.to_csv(path, mode='w', header=True)

    return df
```

At the end, when I call `df = get_info('food_urls.csv', 'food_emails.csv')`, the scraper takes quite a while to run.

When it finished, I ran `df.head()` and got this:

```
    email   link
0   NaN NaN
1   alyssa@therecipecritic.com  https://therecipecritic.com/food-blogger/
2   shop@therecipecritic.com    https://therecipecritic.com/terms/
```

So, it's working, but it's only crawling the first url in the list.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: `for i in url: return urls`? A function can only return once.

Answer (score 0):

Created a python dict with a nested list and imported it:

`from Base_URLS import URL_List`

Then I called it with:

`def get_urls():`

```
 urls = URL_List['urls']
 return urls
```

Worked like a charm!

Thanks for the help @rodrigo-nader